# How do I make a voice-reply via Apple Watch send, and not delay by a variable amount of time?

Tags: messages, apple-watch, watchos

When I send an iMessage on Apple Watch there is only a "don't send" button, but I have no confirmation if/when this message is actually sent.

Many times when I send a message, later to check the time (within 5 seconds or so), the message is still "pending"

How do I

- Get a confirmation that a message was actually sent (as in UX, a whooshing sound, a tap... etc)
- Get rid of the delay when sending an iMessage.  Sometimes when the message is syntactically correct, I want to just go on doing something else, like checking the HopStop's ETA to my destination.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

After you've dictated your message, you can immediately send it by opening Siri and saying "send".

[image: Sending Apple Watch message immediately with Siri]

You can also say "don't send" to cancel your message.

Answer (score 0):

Also, I’ve found that pressing the crown sends it immediately